# Discriminant of multivariable function

Tags: multivariable-calculus, partial-derivative, discriminant

[image]Hey I'm doing an online course and I just can't figure out what I'm doing wrong on one of the questions.

The question is to find the discriminant of the function $$f(x,y) = 5x^2y^2 + 8x^2 + 9y^2$$

The way I solved was I found the first and second partial derivatives of the function with respect to both $x$ and $y$, and I found $f_{xy}$ as well. Then I found the critical point (in my case it ended up being $(0,0)$) and plugged them into the second derivative formulas.

Then I used the discriminant formula from my textbook: $f_{xx}f_{yy}-(f_{xy})^2$

When I solved I got the discriminant as 288, but when I input the answer it comes back as incorrect

Can someone please let me know what I am doing wrong? I have a feeling my critical point is wrong but I'm not sure what else it could be with the given function.

Comment: determinant or discriminant?

Comment: I'm referring to discriminant

Comment: You'll have to show your actual work if you expect any help.

Comment: I posted my work

Comment: doesn't look incorrect to me

Answer (score 1):

$$f(x,y) = 5x^2y^2 + 8x^2 + 9y^2$$
$$f_{xx} = \frac{d}{dx}[2 x (5 y^2 + 8)]=10y^2+16$$
$$f_{yy} = \frac{d}{dy}[2y (5 x^2 + 9)] = 10x^2+18$$
$$f_{xy} = \frac{d}{dy}[2 x (5 y^2 + 8)]=20xy\implies(f_{xy})^2=400x^2y^2$$
$$\text{discriminant } f = ((10y^2+16)(10x^2+18)) - 400x^2y^2$$
$$= (100 x^2 y^2 + 160 x^2 + 180 y^2 + 288) - 400x^2y^2$$
$$\boxed{= -300 x^2 y^2 + 160 x^2 + 180 y^2 + 288}$$
$(0, 0)$ is the correct critical point. And @ $(0, 0)$ the discriminant is $\boxed{288.}$

Make sure you got the equation down correctly, otherwise notify your Professor — the error is on their part.